# Select with multiple where bit data type conditions

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a db for a car dealership that sells new/used cars. I have two tables. One (**CarInfo**) that has all the info about the car(Id, brand, year, isUsed, etc.) and another(**UsedParts**) that contains which parts are available for all used cars. **UsedParts** table consist of bits and a foreign key(**CarInfo's Id**).

I'm trying to construct a query that select all from **UsedParts** where at least one the multiple conditions is accomplished.

This is an example of what the columns I need to query:[image]

An example would be that if I run this query and **HasFrontBumper = 1** it should return all rows that has 1. In other words, should return two rows instead of all rows. Another example would be if **HasRearBumper = 1** and **HasLeftWindshield = 1** it should return two rows.

This is what I've tried so far...

**Query**:
(*Remember; everything that starts with "has", it's data type, is bit*)

```
SELECT * FROM UsedParts WHERE 
HasFrontBumper = 1 OR HasRearBumper = 0 OR HasLeftWindShield = 0 OR HasRightWindShield = 0
```

Tried differnt combinations with `AND` and `OR` but still wasn't working how I want it

Comment: You mentioned multiple examples, but only one query. Please specify which example this corresponds to.

Comment: I've provided my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. When instantiating the query(through java), I pass a string that contains the where clauses. The where conditions will depend on which is true instead of having true and false.

Instead of having:

```
SELECT * FROM UsedParts WHERE 
HasFrontBumper = 1 OR HasRearBumper = 0 OR HasLeftWindShield = 0 OR HasRightWindShield = 0
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM UsedParts WHERE 
HasFrontBumper = 1 OR HasRearBumper = 1 OR HasLeftWindShield = 0 OR HasRightWindShield = 0
```

I would have:

```
SELECT * FROM UsedParts WHERE 
    HasFrontBumper = 1
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM UsedParts WHERE 
HasFrontBumper = 1 OR HasRearBumper = 1
```